# How to use "Tink" in command line to create keys and encrypt data?

Tags: algorithm, cryptography

I have a document that walks through how to determine the appropriate cipher algorithm to encrypt data at rest using *KeyczarTool*; however, it appears that *KeyczarTool* is no longer in use, and "*Tink*" is recommended to be used in its place. Could you help me in creating these keys using the command line?